# iPhone 12, want to use speakerphone with voicemail

Tags: iphone, voicemail

Does anyone know a way to get voicemail to use the speakerphone on an iPhone 12?

It's really inconvenient to have a very quiet whisper give me instructions on digits to press, and speak the messages.   I want those on speakerphone.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. In the Phone tap the Voicemail tab & then tap to select a voicemail. "Unknown" in my example:

[image]

Tap the Speaker icon, then the Play icon:

[image]